# Identifying Unused Letters from an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm writing a hangman program in Java, but the problem I have is, in the game i want to show the remaining letter from the letters guessed, for that I have created a String alpha, which contains the alphabet, and i put that to an ArrayList so i can choose the letters that's been guesses by the player. but i'm stuck in this bit the out put i want to get is as below : and i've attached the code i wrote for the function as well.

You have 6 guesses left.
Available letters: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Please guess a letter: a

### Good guess: a_ _

You have 6 guesses left.
Available letters: bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

### code :

```
public String getRemainingLetters(String[] lettersGuessed) {

    String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";        
    String [] alpha2 = alpha.split("");          
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(alpha2));

    return null;
    // TODO: Fill in your code here
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? And where do you store user's input?

Comment: i have imported a text file that contains up to 55000 words and i have used a random function for the selection of the words, for the users input i'm still working on it.

Comment: So you just want to know how to remove a certain element from your `ArrayList`? `list.remove("a")` (replace `a` with whatever letter you want to remove)

Comment: so my exact requirement is to implement the function, which is to be used to generate a string comprised of letters that have not yet been guessed. The function has to takes a single argument "lettersGuessed", and array of letters (strings) that the user has previously guessed. and implement a behavior to compare these letters against the full alphabet to determine the letters that remain and return them as a string. EXAMPLE : bdfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ( Letters minus letters_guessed )

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have an `ArrayList` of remaining letters and remove a letter at a time as the user inputs them?
If you still want to go with your approach, I guess you could loop through the `ArrayList` of letters already guessed and remove them from the alphabet.

Comment: Okay with your approach I’m not sure how to code it, can you give me a example code.

Comment: Every time you get the user's input, you store it in a variable and do `list.remove(input)`

Comment: Thank Mario I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [List#removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) & [String#join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.Iterable))

Use them as shown below to solve the problem:

```
static String getRemainingLetters(String[] lettersGuessed) {
    String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String[] alpha2 = alpha.split("");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(alpha2));
    List<String> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(lettersGuessed));
    list.removeAll(toBeRemoved);
    return String.join("", list);
}
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(getRemainingLetters(new String[] { "a", "b", "c" }));
        System.out.println(getRemainingLetters(new String[] { "d" }));
        System.out.println(getRemainingLetters(new String[] { "x", "y", "z" }));
        System.out.println(getRemainingLetters(new String[] { "x" }));
    }

    static String getRemainingLetters(String[] lettersGuessed) {
        String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String[] alpha2 = alpha.split("");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(alpha2));
        List<String> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(lettersGuessed));
        list.removeAll(toBeRemoved);
        return String.join("", list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz
```

**An interactive demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder consumed = new StringBuilder();
        final int NO_OF_GUESSES = 6;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String guess;
        for (int i = 1; i <= NO_OF_GUESSES; i++) {
            System.out.println("Available letters: " + getRemainingLetters(consumed.toString().split("")));
            System.out.print("Guess a letter: ");
            guess = kb.nextLine();
            consumed.append(guess.length() >= 1 ? guess.charAt(0) : "");
            System.out.printf("You have %d chances left%n", NO_OF_GUESSES - i);
        }
    }

    static String getRemainingLetters(String[] lettersGuessed) {
        String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String[] alpha2 = alpha.split("");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(alpha2));
        List<String> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(lettersGuessed));
        list.removeAll(toBeRemoved);
        return String.join("", list);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Available letters: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Guess a letter: a
You have 5 chances left
Available letters: bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Guess a letter: x
You have 4 chances left
Available letters: bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz
Guess a letter:
```

Comment: But how do you use the above code with a user input, can you send a demo

Comment: I've added a random function to the code to select a random word from a text file but, but I can not seem to just get one random word from the text file, and use that computer generated word as the hangman word that is to be guessed. I'm updating the above code for reference.

Comment: @chinthanadissanayake - Please post a new question instead of editing this question; otherwise, the future visitors will easily get confused with this answer. Once you have posted the question, you can post here the link and I'll look into that.

Comment: Kumar Avinash      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358012/choosing-a-random-word-from-a-text-file

Answer (score 0):

Here you can pretty it up and put error checking im out of time:)

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main
{
  public static List < String > getRemainingLetters (ArrayList < String >
                             lettersGuessed)
  {
    String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      String[] alpha1 = alpha.split ("");
      ArrayList < String > alpha2 = new ArrayList <> (Arrays.asList (alpha1));
    for (int i = 0; i < lettersGuessed.size (); i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < alpha2.size (); j++)
          {
            if (alpha2.get (j).equals (lettersGuessed.get (i)))
              {
            alpha2.remove (j);
            break;
              }
          }
      }
    return alpha2;
  }


  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    int numGuesses = 10;
    String w = "this";
    String[]word = w.split ("");
    ArrayList < String > wList = new ArrayList <> (Arrays.asList (word));
    ArrayList < String > wAnswer = new ArrayList < String > (wList.size ());
    for (int i = 0; i < wList.size (); i++)
      {
        wAnswer.add ("_ ");
      }
    int left = wList.size();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    boolean notDone = true;
    ArrayList < String > lettersGuessed = new ArrayList < String > ();

    while (notDone)
      {
        System.out.println ();
        String sOut = "";

        List < String > lettersLeft = getRemainingLetters (lettersGuessed);
          for (String s:lettersLeft)
          {
            sOut += s + " ";
          }
        System.out.println ("Letters Left: " + sOut );

        sOut = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < wList.size (); i++)
          {
            sOut += wAnswer.get (i);
          }
        System.out.println (sOut + " Guesses left:" + numGuesses);
        System.out.print ("Enter a letter(* exit): ");
        String sIn = scanner.next ();
        numGuesses--;
        if (sIn.equals ("*")){
          break;
        }
        lettersGuessed.add (sIn);
        for (int i = 0; i < wList.size (); i++)
          {
            if (sIn.equals (wList.get (i)))
              {
                wAnswer.set (i, sIn);
                left--;
              }
          }
          if(left == 0){
              System.out.println ("Congradulations you guessed it!");
              break;
          }
          if(numGuesses == 0){
              System.out.println ("You failed...:(");
              break;
          }

      }


  }

}
```

Comment: this was really helpful