# Choosing a Random word from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, random

I'm trying to develop a hangman as an assignment, and is unable to get one random word from a Text file(which has various words and each word is separated with a space). I've written a code to get a random word, but unable to pick one words and replace it, with the sample string (String w = "this";) i have in the "Function()".

```
 public String randomWord(String wordran) {

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Main\\words.txt"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (line != null) {
            String[] wordline = line.split(" ");
            for (String word : wordline) {
                words.add(word);
            }
            Random rand = new Random();
            String randomWord1 = words.get(rand.nextInt(words.size()));
            //System.out.println("rand word : " + randomWord1);

        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return wordran;


}


   public void function(){

    int numGuesses = 10;
    String w = randomWord();

    String[] word = w.split("");
    ArrayList< String> wList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(word));
    ArrayList< String> wAnswer = new ArrayList< String>(wList.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < wList.size(); i++) {
        wAnswer.add("_ ");
    }
    int left = wList.size();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean notDone = true;
    ArrayList< String> lettersGuessed = new ArrayList< String>();

    while (notDone) {
        System.out.println();
        String sOut = "";

        List< String> lettersLeft = getRemainingLetters(lettersGuessed);
        for (String s : lettersLeft) {
            sOut += s + " ";
        }
        System.out.println("Letters Left: " + sOut);

        sOut = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < wList.size(); i++) {
            sOut += wAnswer.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println(sOut + " Guesses left:" + numGuesses);
        System.out.print("Enter a letter(* exit): ");
        String sIn = scanner.next();
        numGuesses--;
        if (sIn.equals("*")) {
            break;
        }
        lettersGuessed.add(sIn);
        for (int i = 0; i < wList.size(); i++) {
            if (sIn.equals(wList.get(i))) {
                wAnswer.set(i, sIn);
                left--;
            }
        }
        if (left == 0) {
            System.out.println("Congradulations you guessed it!");
            break;
        }
        if (numGuesses == 0) {
            System.out.println("You failed...:(");
            break;
        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Main ma = new Main();

    ma.function();

    loadWords();

   // ma.randomWord();

}
```

Comment: HINT: it would be helpful if the `void randomWord()` method were instead defined as `String randomWord()`, so that you could now write `String w = randomWord();` inside of `function()`.

Comment: @Kevin as you mentioned I've changed it to 'public String randomWord()', and returned a null value and wrote 'String w = randomWord();' inside of' function()'. but for some reason, the code it not running.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific than "not running"?  Also, please update this post to show the code changes you made.

Comment: @KevinAnderson, Ive updated the above code with the changes.

Comment: Well, I can see why it's not working.  If `randomWord` is defined as `String randomWord(String wordran)`, then you have to pass a `String` argument when you call it, as in `String w = randomWord(someStringVariableOrLiteral);`.  Had you just left it as `String randomArgument()`, then `String w = randomWord();` would have been OK.  So now you need to ask yourself "Why did I add that `String` argument to `randomWord`, an argument that it didn't have before and always got along fine without?"

Comment: As you mention i ve just kept it as it is , and made the changes as you suggested. but it doesn't give me any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems with your code:

1. You don't need to pass the parameter, `String wordran` to store the random word. A useful parameter can be `String path` through which you can pass the path of the file to the function.
2. You've missed reading the content from the file in the loop. You've read just the first line.
3. You haven't returned the random word which you have calculated by applying `Random#nextInt`.

On a side note, I recommend you use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to get rid of closing `BufferedReader` explicitly.

Given below is the correct code incorporating these comments:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getRandomWord("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Main\\words.txt"));
    }

    public static String getRandomWord(String path) throws IOException {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] wordline = line.split("\\s+");
                for (String word : wordline) {
                    words.add(word);
                }
            }
        }
        Random rand = new Random();
        return words.get(rand.nextInt(words.size()));
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Arvind Kumar Avinash, I've tried your code. but when i call the String w = getRandomWord("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Main\\words.txt") code in 'Function()' method an runtime exception comes. So how do you add your method to the function (). to get a random word

Comment: `String w = getRandomWord("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Main\\words.txt");` is the right syntax. Can you post the exception?